# background-color not visible

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am trying to design two 'headers' for a webpage. The first is visible whereas the second is not. The place holder works fine also. The code I am using is as follows.

```
.header {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 512;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 10;
        font-size: 18px;
}
.placeholder{
        height: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 18;
}
.header2 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 512;
        height: 50px;
        background color: black;
        z-index: 9;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: -18;
}
```

and then further on I am implementing.

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="file:///C:/Users/wrigh/AppData/Roaming/Sublime%20Text%202/Packages/User/htmlpro.html">REFRESH</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">TWITTER</a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com">INSTAGRAM</a>
    <a href="https:www.youtube.com">YOUTUBE</a>
</div>
<div class="placeholder">
</div>
<div class="header2">
    <a href="https://www.gooogle.co.uk">GOOGLE</a>
</div>
```

I am pretty confused since the header is almost identical to header2. I've messed around to try and find the problem and it seems as if the second header is transparent. I added in `opacity` but nothing seemed to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `background color: black;`

The property is named `background-color`.

> `min-width: 512;`
>   `margin-top: -18;`

Those are wrong as well, since they are missing a unit.

You should check your CSS for errors, https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: That is bad. Thank you and sorry. Thanks for the link also, was going to ask about something similar to that.

Comment: Note that in quirks mode, unitless length values are OK; those get interpreted as px.

Comment: @MrLister: Quirks Mode means “please ignore my errors, and try to guess what I might have meant” – and that is not really something you want. For reliable results cross-browser, you want to avoid Quirks Mode at all cost.

Comment: @CBroe While I sympathise with your disgust of Quirks Mode, it's  something to be aware of, especially in cases like this, where we can't see the OP's webpage and we've no idea if there's a DOCTYPE or not.

Comment: @MrLister: I think we can agree that even if quirks mode lets a browser interpret wrong CSS values still as they might have been intented, there is usually no good reason to leave them in the CSS in the first place. Validating it to find such errors is easy, and who knows what possible future problems it might help avoid …